# Android - is there a way to add an options menu to a listItem

Tags: android, android-layout

I display some items as a list and I was wondering whether there was a way to add a little dropdown to the right of the screen for each item in the list giving the options of delete/edit.

Is that possible? Rigth now I list things like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >


<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>    


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/no_problems"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter the business(es) you want to plan or choose from your existing list."
    />          


    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>

        <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_problem_ok"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue" 
    android:text="Plan a New Business"
    android:layout_marginTop ="15dp"    
    />  
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the listView I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you add a context menu to each item,that way , a menu will pop up if the user touches the item for approx 2 seconds, You can add all the  options there.
It will also help in reducing the clutter.

Comment: @amanmadaan yes that migth be nice, but many users wouldnt know to touch the menu for 2 seconds :)

Comment: I think you should give it a try, context menus are a standard these days and all the regular Android users know how they work. You can add some info about them in a help file or a pop up.
Well, i  have presented my case :), Just in case you find that they are right for you, feel free to have a look at 
[this](https://github.com/appliedXml/Tarang/blob/master/src/com/bvp/miniproject/ViewSavedMessagesActivity.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add spinner in ur list item layout, then set adapter to tat spinner with in getView() method.

for ex. ur list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
 <TextView android:id="@+id/nameTV" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>  

<Spinner android:id="@+id/actionSP" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then UR getView()

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,
                    null);
            viewHolder.nameTV = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

            viewHolder.actionSP = (Spinner) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.actionSP);

            ArrayAdapter<String> reasonAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    mApplication, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    mYourActionsArray);

            reasonAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            viewHolder.actionSP.setAdapter(reasonAdapter);

            viewHolder.actionSP
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        }
                    });
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.nameTV.setText("Some Value");
```

return view;
        }

ViewHolder class

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameTV;
    Spinner actionSP;
}
```

Comment: I have not worked with spinners before.  Is it another name for a small drop-down menu item?  Also, I am not sure how to add that drop-down menu item to the right side of the listitem in the layout xml.

Comment: ya spinner s d name of drop-down menu in android, i've update my answer with layout

Answer (score 2):

If u want to look good then use `quickaction-dialog` for Option Menu.
here the whole example [quickaction-dialog](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: thanks, I looked through it but I am not sure I understand how to get the layout to render it in any reasonable way.